# WordPress Running Slow with Amazon RDS

Tags: wordpress, nginx, server, varnish

I'm working on a server containing a WordPress installation located at http://67.225.176.58/ which is using Nginx, Varnish, and HH-VM and is running really slowly. I was using PHP-FPM with the same results. Please see my Nginx configuration to see how I have it set up and I can give any other configuration files needed. I can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

```
nginx.conf
     worker_processes 24;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    pid /run/nginx.pid;
    events {
        worker_connections 50000;
    }

    http {
        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    gzip on;
            gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_min_length 1100;
            gzip_vary on;
            gzip_proxied any;
            gzip_comp_level 2;
     gzip_buffers 4 32k;
            gzip_http_version 1.1;
            gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
        sendfile            on;
        tcp_nopush          on;
        tcp_nodelay         on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;
        include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type        application/octet-stream;
        # increase buffer and timeouts
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    client_body_buffer_size 10K;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    client_max_body_size 8m;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
    client_body_timeout 12;
    client_header_timeout 12;
    keepalive_timeout 15;
    send_timeout 10;
        # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
        # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
        # for more information.
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
        server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  host.friendshipcollar.com;
     # note that these lines are originally from the "location /" block
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
    }
    }


friendshipcollar.com.conf
    server {
        listen 80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        root /usr/share/nginx/friendshipcollar.com;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name 67.225.176.58 friendshipcollar.com  www.friendshipcollar.com;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

    location ~* \.html$ {
      expires -1;
    }

    location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
      expires 168h;
      add_header Pragma public;
      add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }
        location /doc/ {
            alias /usr/share/doc/;
       autoindex on;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            allow ::1;
            deny all;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/friendshipcollar.com;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to PHP-FPM server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache’s document root
        # concurs with nginx’s one
        #
      # location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny all;
       # }
    }
```

Comment: You may have better luck asking this at http://serverfault.com/